# Does iOS Per-App VPN require MDM

Tags: ios, mdm

Does iOS Per-App VPN require use of MDM?

Is there any other way in which this feature can be utilized?

So far my finding has been that it can only be used with MDM. [See Routing Network Data to the VPN Section](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkExtension/Reference/NETunnelProviderManagerClassRef/index.html)

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do that would require a per-app VPN outside of a managed environment?

Comment: @duskwuff I am working on a solution where I want all the traffic from one particular app on end-user's device to be routed to my network.

Comment: What, like an application you didn't develop?

Comment: @duskwuff yes in my case app is developed by end-user or some other 3rd party. I had considered SDK based approach to configure proxy programmatically(overriding NSURLProtocol, setting proxy in NSURLSessionConfiguration). But I will prefer per-app VPN solution(if I can get it to work) since it does not require any SDK integration. But per-app VPN is only feasible if it works without MDM.

Comment: You may consider using Mobile Secure Gateway from https://www.teskalabs.com - that's an in-app secure tunnel that doesn't depend on MDM.
Disclosure: I work at TeskaLabs, a company that is behind this product.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, technically it is possible to configure an app to use a Per-App VPN without an MDM. However, this is purely for development of your own VPN plugin and will not work for apps pushed to the app store.

> **Testing Per-App VPN**
>
> As described above, an MDM server is required to configure Per-App VPN
>   for VPN apps distributed via the App Store. To make testing Per-App
>   VPN easier, it is possible to configure Per-App VPN without an MDM
>   server during development by using the NETestAppMapping Info.plist
>   key.
>
> The NETestAppMapping Info.plist key can only be used to create app
>   rules in apps that are signed with a Development provisioning profile.
>   In apps that are signed with Distribution provisioning profiles the
>   NETestAppMapping Info.plist key has no effect.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension/netunnelprovidermanager